# Logstash: how to forward logs to Redis broker from python?

Tags: python, redis, logstash

How can I configure a logstash agent that sends python logs to the redis broker?

I saw there's an option using "beaver" as a background deamon but I would rather choose a python module that configured to send it directly instead of doing it in the non-direct way.

Currently I'm using [Python-Logstash](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-logstash), but I think it doesn't support inserting messages to Redis queue.

Comment: What is the reason you don't want to use beaver client? It is very efficient and takes little resources.

Comment: Good question. Seems to me that it is a bad design that each module rights to the disk and then the "beaver" will have to handle it in the background on the agent. Am I wrong?

Comment: At first it might seem like it is a waste of resources but think about the fact that you need to implement code logic that has nothing to do with your main application and it will need to handle connections to Redis, do it efficiently, handle re-connections and disconnections, handle API changes in Redis and so on.

This is not your main business and unless you are very limited on resources and you plan to send huge amounts of data, I think that you should consider using a shipper - It will make your life much easier.

Comment: Update the question with your logstash configuration file...